# Knockout.js Multiple dropdown lists.

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

So, hello! Ive been trying to make a simple simple feature work with Knockout.js, but to no success. Been looking through forums and posts but still, no luck!

So what i am trying to do is fill a few dropdown boxes with information from ObservableArrays. This is the code i have so far. But nothing att all is seen except the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function location(name, id) {
            var self = this;

            self.Name = name;
            self.Id = id;
        }

        function attraction(name, price) {
            var self = this;

            self.Name = name;
            self.Price = price;
        }

        function transportation(name, price) {
            var self = this;

            self.Name = name;
            self.Price = price;
        }

        function BookingViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            self.currentLocation = ko.observableArray([
                new location("Istanbul", "0"),
                new location("Ankara", "1"),
                new location("Izmir", "2")
            ]);
            self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();

            self.targetAttraction = ko.observableArray([
                new attraction("Aspendos Theatre", "200"),
                new attraction("Library of Celsus", "150"),
                new attraction("Hagia Sophia", "140")
            ]);
            self.selectedAttraction = ko.observable();

            self.transportationMode = ko.observableArray([
                new transportation("Walk", "0"),
                new transportation("Bus", "50"),
                new transportation("Train", "75")
            ]);
            self.selectedTransportation = ko.observable();
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new BookingViewModel());
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="main-search-content">
        From: <select data-bind="
            options: currentLocation,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'name',
            optionsCaptation: 'Select....'
        "></select>
        To: <select data-bind="
            options: targetAttraction,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'price',
            optionsCaptation: 'Select....'
        "></select>
        How: <select data-bind="
            options: transportationMode,
            optionsText: 'name',
            optionsValue: 'price',
            optionsCaptation: 'Select....'
        "></select>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you might have guessed im rather new to javascript in general, but i do my best to try and learn. ive done all the tutorials on the website, but so far with this, it havent helped me find a solution. Would appriciate ANY help or hints.

Best regards,

Comment: You used `$(document)` but you did not include jQuery.

Comment: Added now, thanks i totally missed that. Still, no change tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optionsText` and `optionsValue` values are case sensitive, so you need `'Name'`, not `'name'`.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGXqA/) of this working as it should.